Buying a new ThinkPad. What CPU would I need for Ubuntu?
I am currently looking to replace my laptop running Ubuntu 24.01.1 LTS and I am looking at a ThinkPad. I currently have an AMD 5625U right now and it works flawlessly.
I am on this forum, because I bought a ThinkPad e16 gen2 recently, with the AMD Ryzen 7 7735 HS and installed Ubuntu (Gnome). And it would lag after 1 hour opened, doing basically nothing, like the cursor wasn't following the mouse, apps would take longer to load than my older laptop, despite being newer, nothing was "snappy".
I returned this computer, because of the CPU, because it would simply NOT function on any Linux distros, (I have also tested Manjaro KDE and Gnome). People there told me that HS series was simply not working on Linux, someone bought a Tuxedo with the 7840HS and it was the same apparently. (Network and fingerprint scanner worked though!)
However, not all hope is lost. ThinkPad is selling the same computer, with different options I wanted to know if any of you guys have experience with the different processors:

Ryzen 7 7735U (no extra cost)
Ryzen 5 7535U (no extra cost)
Intel Core Ultra 7 155U (+170$ than AMD)
Intel Core Ultra 7 155H (+200$ than AMD)

My work consist of programming, JetBrains or vscode, watching youtube, multi task and in term of gaming nothing fancy (Minecraft...). My current laptop does run all of this already, with an older CPU.
Budget is 1k at most, this one cost 997$ here. Intel adds about 200$...
I am not looking for a ThinkPad specially, but it was my dream laptop: 16:10, 16", 2500x1600, 400nits, 57wh battery with a good backlit keyboard
Shops in my country only sell the same HP over and over again, Asus seems overpriced so I kinda settled for the E16 with another CPU. There are no other 16" laptops with this type of screen, battery, keyboard and aspect ratio.

If your current laptop does all of this currently, why are you looking to upgrade? Also, what country are you in?

Linux is an amazingly good operating system, but the one thing it can lack is support for modern hardware.  As a general guideline, if your hardware is commonplace and not too new, the Linux will be happy.  For cutting-edge hardware, macOS is the way to go (but good luck affording Apple products), and unfortunately, closed-source Windows still tends to fare much better than Linux.
As you discovered, when Linux's support for hardware is lacking, performance suffers (and crashes are likely).
For this reason, of the choices you mentioned, I recommend either of the Intel processors.  I know it's trendy to harp on Intel, but the reality is they have the largest CPU market share, and Linux (including Ubuntu) generally supports Intel processors without issue.  The only issues I've had with Linux on Intel-based systems is a lack of appropriate cooling fan use.  Linux tends to be significantly lighter on the CPU (and memory) than Windows, but I've noticed cooling fans coming on much more frequently on Linux boxes than on Windows boxes.
I hope this helps you.
